# Wrong label for a nodereference in Drupal content-type

Tags: drupal, view, cck

We have a content-type built using CCK.  One of the fields is a node reference.  The node picker is using a view to build the options.

A few days ago, everything was working well.

Today, it looks like all node reference fields using views to populate the selection options are displaying the wrong label.  Every single label in the option is ``A'', but the actual node number is correct.  The form actually works, just the labels are incorrect.

We have tried just about every combination of edit/save, disable/enable, reboot, clear cache, clone the view, rebuild the view, new view, etc, but we still have a big list of As.

If we create a brand new content type with a brand new node reference field, we get the problem.

Through some backup/restore exercises, we have determined that the problem is actually in the database and not in the code.

We can restore our last good backup, but we will lose a decent amount of work we have put into other parts of the database.

We enabled mysql query logging, and the view is actually being called properly, but we cannot track down where the problem is creeping in after that (unraveling the CCK / Views / Drupal plumbing is a challenge).

The install was build with latest stable versions as of April.

The problems referred to in http://drupal.org/node/624422 is similar, but our code versions include the patches mentioned.

Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, we built a new Drupal instance from latest stables, cloned the database, and had the new instance use the clone.  Everything is OK now.

We have been going through our SVN logs and can't find anything that would suggest that someone edited core or an actual module file.

We are currently chalking this up to gremlins as we can't dedicate any more time to the problem (or do the anti-test of the old code with a clean database), but I would love to hear any ideas.

Comment: That's quite a mystery. I suggest checking out the Features module as a method to surgically export some of your work out of the mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses.  We finally got to the bottom of this.

There was a module that was doing a custom hook_views_post_render() that did a prep_replace to rewrite some output.  Unknown to us, there are instances where the $output parameter isn't a string, but an array, and this was causing the problem.  One of those instances happens to be when you attach a view to a build a select in CCK.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with using views for node reference, after quite a lot of hair pulling it turned out to be that my caching layer was buggy. I was using memcached, but memcached wasn't truned on on the server. It may be worth checking.